# How to configure Loopback mongodb connection to replicaset with ssl (x.509)

Tags: mongodb, ssl, x509, loopback

I am try to configure connection to **mongodb** (with replica set and enabled security x.509)  for loopback. 
Loopback has following options for connect:

```
{
  "db": {
    "host": "",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": ""
    "database": "",
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

I know that I need to fill "url" field, but I have not ideas how to add information about certificate.
My url not working: `"mongodb://example1.host.com:11111,example2.host.com:11111,example2.host.com:11111/some_db?replicaSet=replica_set_0&readPreference=primary&authSource=$external&ssl=true&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&clientCertPath=/usr/...../user.pem&rootCAPath=/usr/.../mongodb-CA-cert.crt"`

Please provide really working config.

Comment: did you get any solution?